# How do you use a while loop with user input?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Max {
   
   public int findMax() {
      /* Type your code here. */
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int userInput = scan.nextInt();
      int largestInt = 0;
      
      while (userInput > 0) {
         if (userInput > largestInt) {
            largestInt = userInput;
         }
      }
      return largestInt;
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Max test = new Max();
      System.out.println(test.findMax());
   }
}
```

This is being tested on Zybooks, and everything I have tried has resulted in the program timing out. I can't figure out why! I think my while loop is very logical, what am I missing?

```
1:Compare output
0 / 1
Program timed out
Output differs. See highlights below.
Input
2 77 17 4 -1
Your output

Expected output
77
```

If userInput is greater than largestInt, assign userInt value to largestValue until userInt is negative, and return largestInt.

Comment: **1)** There is nothing in the loop that changes the value of `userInput`. So, `while (userInput > 0)` will either loop forever (when `userInput > 0`) or never (when `userInput <= 0`.  **2)** You might want `int userInput = scan.nextInt();` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop condition is based on `userInput`, which doesn't change inside the loop.